# Convert text file data to table

Tags: text-processing, awk, conversion

I have a text file with 2 columns which I would like to convert to a table.
The below image is just what it looks like in the file, not a table. Formatting is putting all my text in one line when posting the question.

This is what the data looks like in the file:

```
name: name1
copies: 3
copy1: name1copy1
copy2: name1copy2
copy3: name1copy3
name: name2
copies: 1
copy1: name2copy1
name: name3
copies: 2
copy1: name3copy1
copy2: name3copy2
```

This is what I would like to get out:

```
name,copies,copy1,copy2,copy3  
name1,3,name1copy1,name1copy2,name1copy3
name2,1,name2copy1,bull,null
name3,2,name3copy1,name3copy2,null
```

From here I can import into excel.

Comment: I am trying to use awk, but my knowledge is very limited. I am trying to learn awk, sed and grep to manipulate text

Comment: If the key `name:` is fixed, then `awk` will be a good tool.

Comment: Can the string `: ` appear anywhere in any of your `name*copy*` text? It's always better to give realistic examples of data rather than just [variations of] one simple string everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses GNU awk for multidimensional arrays: it reads all the data in one pass and emits the output in the END block. This is "script.awk"

```c
BEGIN {FS = ": "}

!($1 in head) {head[$1] = h++}
$1 == "name"  {name = $2}
{data[name][$1] = $2}

END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"

    # print the header
    sep=""
    for (item in head) {
        printf "%s%s", sep, item
        sep = ","
    }
    printf "\n"

    # print the data
    for (name in data) {
        sep=""
        for (item in head) {
            printf "%s%s", sep, data[name][item]
            sep = ","
        }
        printf "\n"
    }
}
```

then:

```
$ gawk -f script.awk file
name,copies,copy1,copy2,copy3
name1,3,name1copy1,name1copy2,name1copy3
name2,1,name2copy1,,
name3,2,name3copy1,name3copy2,
```

Comment: Not implemented: ensuring valid CSV by quoting a field if it contains commas or double quotes